# What is the difference between generating Range and NumericRange in Scala

Tags: scala, collections, range, scala-2.13

I am new to Scala, and I tried to generate some Range objects.

```
val a = 0 to 10
// val a: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive = Range 0 to 10
```

This statement works perfectly fine and generates a range from 0 to 10. And `to` keyword works without any imports.

But when I try to generate a NumericRange with floating point numbers, I have to import some functions from BigDecimal object as follows, to use `to` keyword.

```
import scala.math.BigDecimal.double2bigDecimal
val f = 0.1 to 10.1 by 0.5
// val f: scala.collection.immutable.NumericRange.Inclusive[scala.math.BigDecimal] = NumericRange 0.1 to 10.1 by 0.5
```

Can someone explain the reason for this and the mechanism behind range generation.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The import you are adding adds "automatic conversion" from `Double` to `BigDecimal` as the name suggests.

It's necessary because `NumericRange` only works with types `T` for which `Integral[T]` exists and unfortunately it doesn't exist for `Double` but exists for `BigDecimal`.

Bringing tha automatic conversion in scope makes the `Double`s converted in `BigDecimal` so that `NumericRange` can be applied/defined.

You could achieve the same range without the import by declaring directly the numbers as `BigDecimal`s:

```scala
BigDecimal("0.1") to BigDecimal("10.1") by BigDecimal("0.5")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please explain what it means for a number to be integral? I tried to find the reason and most sources says that integrals are similar to integers. But it seems like that's not the case in this scenario.